# How to align text and image in cardview?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-linearlayout, cardview

i have designed a layout where data will come from recyclerview. Problem i am facing is i am unable to align items.

Below is the snippet image.

[image]

this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="prnce"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/groupname"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/groupCount"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>
            <ImageButton

                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/myhomegrey"
                android:id="@+id/homeWindow"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/stargrey"
                android:id="@+id/favorite"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </ImageButton>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i align every item at center so they can come in line so that if textview text size increase or decrease it should not affect the alignment of other layouts

Answer (score 0):

The weights you are assigning are causing the excess space to be distributed evenly among the widgets. Specify a weight for the text field "groupName" and remove the weights for the other fields. This will assign all excess space to the "groupName" text view. This will also push all the other widgets to the right. You can assign margins or padding to space those widgets out.

You may also want to consider assigning a specific size to the text view "groupCount".

An alternative to this would be to use *ConstraintLayout*.